# How to have a number to be a power?

Tags: javascript, html, math, input, calculator

My Javascript has this:

```
(A + B) ? C
```

I have everything else, but how do i have C to be a power? I thought using ^ would work, but it just adds it.

Comment: It doesn't add it, it XORs it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript does not have an operator for exponentiation. `^` is actually the [bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Try using [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) instead:

```
var d = Math.pow(a + b, c);
```